# methods in template, that accepts all types from the same template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template specialization, that I'd like to give a second set of "copy constructor" -like methods to, that can accept every version of it's own template.  Similar to how a `shared_ptr<Anything>` can be given or copied to a `shared_ptr<void>` to enable type erasure?  It's difficult to describe outside of code, I hope this clarifies what I mean:

```
// primary template
template<class T>
class Foobar {
    Foobar(const Foobar<T> & foo);
    Foobar(Foobar<T> && foo);
    Foobar<T> & operator=(const Foobar<T> & foo);
    Foobar<T> & operator=(Foobar<T> && foo);
};

// template specialized for char
template<>
class Foobar<char> {
    // these copy constructors exist for itself, but...
    Foobar(const Foobar<char> & foo);
    Foobar(Foobar<char> && foo);
    Foobar<char> & operator=(const Foobar<char> & foo);
    Foobar<char> & operator=(Foobar<char> && foo);

    // I would also like to have all Foobar<Type>, regardless of what "Type" is, 
    // be accepted into these methods
    // (it's okay if the earlier Foobar<char> copy constructors must be removed)
    Foobar(const Foobar<???> & foo);
    Foobar(Foobar<???> && foo);
    Foobar<char> & operator=(const Foobar<???> & foo);
    Foobar<char> & operator=(Foobar<???> && foo);
};
```

Is there a way to do this and have it be ergonomic to write, like this?

```
Foobar<int>  fooInt;
Foobar<char> fooMemory;

fooMemory = std::move(fooInt);  // angle brackets hurt to type...
```

Comment: `template <typename U> Foobar(const Foobar<U> &foo);`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - oh... it was that easy, it... just deduces the type at the call-site without me needing to do anything extra.  I have no idea why I thought it'd be anything different.  I even learned about SFINAE just 1 hour ago.  pff thanks!

Comment: @AnneQuinn O well SFINAE is a good tool to know anyway. So don't consider it wasted time :)